# Data Type for all products

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

what would be the DataType of the Quantity column for all the products in a product table of a shop in sql?
Like there are lots of products which are measured in different units like litre, gm, KG, pieces etc. Using which Data Type in the table I can take my inputs with the corresponding units of the products from the form?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [ask] and [faq] and the edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to make two columns to store this value.

**The First Column** is `Quantity` this could be `integer` or `bigint` you can define it as you need to store the number value of quantity.

**The Second Column** is `QuantityType` this could be a `smallint` storing just a number refering to your quantity types like Kilo, Liter, gm etc...

**Note** I choose smallint for `QuantityType` because i dont think there will be types greater than this data type if you find it more than this you can define it as `integer`

Answer (score 0):

For a quantity column I would use a [decimal column type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) with the appropriate precision (i.e. if you specify a precision of 15 and a scale of 5 then you will be able to store up to 9,999,999,999 with up to 5 decimal places). You would then also need to have a column that specifies the units, this could be a lookup (foreign key) to another table.

Before you use an int or bigint consider whether you need to store fractional quantities - if you do then you would also need to store a multiplier, i.e. if your quantity is for kilograms you would need to store the amount in grams but then multiply by 1000 (because an int/bigint cannot store fractional amounts).